# javap -c does not give me bytecode of methods

Tags: java, bytecode, javap

I have a java file looking like this:

```
package answers;

class finalRed{
    private long l;
    public synchronized void increment(){
        l++;
    }
    public void decrement(){
        synchronized(this){
            l--;
        };
    }
}
```

And I need to view the bytecode of each of the methods, and I know that I should use the javap command. I need a output like this:

```
public synchronized void increment();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: dup
       2: getfield      #2                  // Field l:J
       5: lconst_1
       6: ladd
       7: putfield      #2                  // Field l:J
      10: return

  public void decrement();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: dup
       2: astore_1
       3: monitorenter
       4: aload_0
       5: dup
       6: getfield      #2                  
       9: lconst_1
      10: lsub
      11: putfield      #2                  
      14: aload_1
      15: monitorexit
      16: goto          24
      19: astore_2
      20: aload_1
      21: monitorexit
      22: aload_2
      23: athrow
      24: return
```

However, running `javap -c C:\Users\Ask\Git\ITUProj\PCPP-private-Garse\week01\code\answers\finalRed.class` (which I can read should work), renders me this output:

```
Compiled from "finalRed.java"
public class answers.finalRed {
  public answers.finalRed();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
}
```

Which doesn't actually show me any code from the two methods. Running javap with -v or -verbose doesn't help either. How should I run the command to get the actual bytecode of the two methods in the class?

My java version is 12.01

Comment: Use the `-v` flag.

Comment: http://sscce.org/ Is your actual method private?  Do you need the `-private` flag?

Comment: Have you tried the Krakatau disassembler? It's more reliable than javap. https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau

Comment: I can't reproduce this (Java 15.0.1), using javap -c <path-to-class> shows me (approximately) your expected output. What is your exact javac version? How did you compile this?

Comment: The outputs do not match. Your source code shows a non-public class and the javap output shows a public class. Perhaps, there are even more mismatches, so I’d follow @Brett Kail’s assumption. Use `-p` or `-private` to show private members.

Comment: my methods are public as in the code given, my java version is 12.01

Comment: adding -p doesnt change anything

Comment: Even if I repeat myself: *The outputs do not match*. The class file has not been compiled from the source code version you have posted.